# Geb Navigator Missing method exception

Tags: automation, geb

I am using the Geb framework to automate some browser tasks.

This line of code:

!$("h4", 0, text:"Buildings").isEmpty()

is throwing a groovy.lang.MissingMethodException:

groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: geb.navigator.NonEmptyNavigator.$() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap, java.lang.String, java.lang.Integer) values: [[text:Buildings], h4, 0]
Possible solutions: tag(), tag(), any(), eq(int), is(java.lang.String), is(java.lang.String)

The Geb documentation provides an example which should perform the same task as my line:

> The following is a concrete example…
>
> $("h1", 2, class: "heading")
>
> This would find the 3rd (elements are 0 indexed) h1 element whose class attribute is exactly
> “heading”.

Can anyone shed any light on why my code isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such method in the api in which you can specify selector, index and a map of attributes.

You can on the other hand get the result you're expecting using the following:

```
$("h1", class: "heading").eq(2)
```